# Is it safe to set up references in the following manner

Tags: c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2012, reference

Can anyone tell me whether this is safe and defined:

---

```
class RefClass
{
public:
    RefClass(int i) { this->i = i; }
    int& GetRef() { return i; }
private:
    int i; 
};


RefClass rc(10);

int* refp;

{
    refp = &rc.GetRef();
}

*refp = 20;
```

---

Specifically I am concerned with the lifetime of the returned reference in the nested scope and whether it can be referenced in that scope and then later dereferenced as an lvalue after that scope has dissolved.

This code compiles and runs as expected in VS2012, but that doesn't mean it will in the next version, so I am trying to find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

The returned reference is a temporary, lasting until the end of the statement containing the function call. It's used within its lifetime to set `refp` to point to its target, `rc.i`. It's not needed to dereference the pointer after that.

The only danger is if the object might be destroyed, leaving the pointer dangling:

```
int* refp;

{
    RefClass rc(10);
    refp = &rc.GetRef();
} // rc is destroyed here

*refp = 20; // BOOM!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is all right. You'd have issues in the following case:

```
int* refp;

{
    RefClass rc(10);
    refp = &rc.GetRef();
}

*refp = 20;
```

Comment: your answer is also correct, but giving the credit to the other answer for the greater explanation.